# setRadiusCorner just at the bottom of the view

Tags: view, uiview, calayer, layer, cornerradius

i have a view with rounded corners.
I want to make it rounded just at the two bottom corners of the view.
How can i do that?

This is my code that makes the rounded corners for the view:

```
CALayer *myLayer = moreInfoView.layer;
[myLayer setCornerRadius:20.0];
[view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Round only the `UIRectCornerBottomLeft` and `UIRectCornerBottomRight` corners:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:yourView.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.frame = yourView.bounds;
layer.path = path.CGPath;
yourView.layer.mask = layer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that with the CALayer with ease - you could subclass NSView and make a simple redraw routine. May be easiest to use http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?RoundedRectangles as a starting point (after removing the two bezier Paths you do not want to have rounded) and then do a simple:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor xxxx] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = ...
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = ...

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPartiallyRoundedRect:rect
           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill or Stroke];

    [path stroke or fill];
}
```

In above link - the second simplified example makes your live easier - as you can simply make two of them 'path lineToPoint: ..'.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! but I find it difficult to implement.. sorry im new in all xcode stuff :)
I can tell you that i have a view that i made graphically on the xib file and the variable of the view called "moreInfoView".
Can you think how can i do that? Thanks